# What line is determined by the following complex equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\left | z+1-i \right |= \frac{\Re z-\Im z}{\sqrt{2}}$$
This leads to the following equation, if we write $z=x+iy$ :
$$\sqrt{\left ( x+1 \right )^{2}+\left( y-1 \right)^2}=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$$
which according to desmos, defines a set in $\mathbb{C}$ which is empty. 
[image]

Comment: $(x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 =(x-y)^2/2$ Does not give an empty set.

See [here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand[%28x%2B1%29^2+%2B+%28y-1%29^2++-+%28x-y%29^2%2F2]+%3D+0)

Comment: @amcalde note that all of the solutions there satisfy $x<y$, i.e. $x-y < 0$, so $x$ and $y$ would not satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there exist $(x,y)$ such that
$$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt 2}$$
(note here that $x-y\ge 0$)

Then we have
$$\begin{align}(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2=\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}&\Rightarrow x^2+y^2+2x-2y+2=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}-xy\\&\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}+xy+2x-2y+2=0\\&\Rightarrow x^2+y^2+2xy+4x-4y+4=0\\&\Rightarrow (x+y)^2+4=4(y-x)\end{align}$$

The LHS is positive and the RHS is non-positive. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed impossible: Using Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
$$ x-y = (1)(x+1) + (-1)(y-1) -2 \le \sqrt{2}\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2} - 2 $$
and hence $\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2}$ for all $x$ and $y$.